# ModelState invalid because <select> gives just id but other attribute is required

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Model `CargoType` with `id` , `name` and few others. When adding new cargo type to database all of them are required, but when i'm adding new object of `Cargo` which have `amount` and `cargoType` for which i use `<select>` to choose from existing ones. Id is what is really choosen in this select but then because `CargoType.Name` is null, ModelState.isValid is false.

**Cargo model:**

```
public class Cargo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public CargoType CargoType { get; set; }
    }
```

**CargoType model:**

```
public class CargoType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; } //in millimeters
        public int Width { get; set; } //in millimeters
        public int Length { get; set; } //in millimeters
        public bool StackingAllowed { get; set; }
    }
```

**Part of the View:**

Order have `List<Cargo> Cargo`

```
@model TransportationManagementSystem.Models.Order

[...]

@for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Cargo[i].Amount" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Cargo[i].Amount" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Cargo[i].Amount" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Cargo[i].CargoType" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="Cargo[i].CargoType.Id" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CargoTypes"></select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Cargo[i].CargoType" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            }
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,PickUpAddress,DropOffAddress,PickUpTime,DropOffTime,OrderState,Cargo")] Order order)
    {
        if (order.Cargo != null)
        {
            foreach (var cargo in order.Cargo)
            {
                var cargoType = await _context.CargoTypes.FindAsync(cargo.CargoType.Id);
                cargo.CargoType = cargoType;
            }
        }
        //ModelState.Clear();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(order);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(order);
    }
```

How should i go about this?

Comment: remove `public CargoType CargoType { get; set; }` from your model (or create a new view model) and replace it with something like `public int CargoTypeId { get; set; }` so that you are just passing the Id instead of the whole object. then your `<select>` whould be `<select asp-for="Cargo[i].CargoTypeId" `

Comment: Yeah i just figured out this. But still, are there other solutions? Im interested if there is a way to disable validation of something in ModelState?

Comment: If you only want to validate the `Name` field in certain situations, then remove the `[Required]` attribute. Then in the actions you want to make it required, check it and add `ModelState.AddModelStateError("CargoType.Name", "Required")` if its not filled out then call `ModelState.IsValid`. I know this is the opposite of what you are asking... but there is no `ModelState.DisableValidationForProperty` or whatever. Just make a view model of the things you want to validate - thats what view models are for - a model for this specific view